# multiple markers at this line in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse shows me: multiple markers at this line for the line: `public void sendConnection(View view)`
If anyone can help me, thank you very much

```
btr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connection);
        btr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordedit);
                String str = text.getText().toString();
                if(str.equals("1234"))
                {
                    public void sendConnection(View view)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddMasterNumber.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    AlertDialog alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                    alertdialog.setTitle("Wrong Password");
                    alertdialog.setIcon(R.drawable.wrongpassword);
                    alertdialog.setMessage("The password you entered is incorrect, please try again!");
                    alertdialog.show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: what is your question???

Comment: My question was to delete Eclipse's problem which shows me: "multiple markers at this line" but i resolved it thanks to "Triode" :)

Comment: the **this** you are passing in sendConnection is referring to the button(this). Simply instead of this call it with YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this.  For e,g  Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, AddMasterNumber.class);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordedit);
    String str = text.getText().toString();
    if(str.equals("1234"))
    {
        sendConnection(v);
    }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertdialog.setTitle("Wrong Password");
        alertdialog.setIcon(R.drawable.wrongpassword);
        alertdialog.setMessage("The password you entered is incorrect, please try again!");
        alertdialog.show();
    }

}


public void sendConnection(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddMasterNumber.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You cannot declare  a function inside another function;.